# Type ... is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CodeLinkContentRightHandSideProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Trying to handle some mouse events for a component in a React/TS app. Not sure where to put the mouse event or how to pass it/the handled event back up from the child prop to the parent prop.

This is the code:

```
const [isMouseOver, setIsMouseOver] = useState(false)

 <ContentRightHandSide
            onMouseEnter={() => setIsMouseOver(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setIsMouseOver(false)}
          > 
           [...]
    </ContentRightHandSide>
```

And this is the code for the ContentRightHandSide Component

```
type ContentRightHandSideProps = {
  children?: ReactNode;
};

export function ContentRightHandSide({
  children,
  offset,
}: ContentRightHandSideProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the error:

```
(property) onMouseEnter: () => any
Type '{ children: Element[]; offset: number; onMouseEnter: () => any; onMouseLeave: () => any; }' 
is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ContentRightHandSideProps'.
Property 'onMouseEnter' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ContentRightHandSideProps'
```

I'd greatly appreciate any assistance offered, thanks!

Comment: show ContentRightHandSide

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka added both components